# How to output two PWM signals, one of 50% duty cycle, the other 25% duty cycle, from an Arduino Uno?

Tags: arduino-uno, pwm

I need to output two PWM signals, one of 50% duty cycle, the other 25% duty cycle, from an Arduino. Feed both signals into the 2 channels of a PicoScope and measure:

a) the time difference between the rising pulse of the traces and
b) the time it takes for the signal to settle for the 50% trace.

I understand that I may not get help with the Picoscope part of the question, however I do need help with the other part.

I'm very new to Arduino and don't really know what I'm doing. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: examine the blinkWithoutDelay example sketch in the Arduimo IDE ... use that for timing the rising and falling edges of the two signals

Answer (score 1):

The function `analogWrite` generates PWM signals. See [its documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/analog-io/analogwrite/) for details.

You use `analogWrite(pin_for_25_percent, 64);` for 25% and `analogWrite(pin_for_50_percent, 128);` for 50%.

```cpp
const int pin_for_25_percent = /* your choice */;
const int pin_for_50_percent = /* your choice */;

void setup() {
    analogWrite(pin_for_25_percent, 64);
    analogWrite(pin_for_50_percent, 128);
}

void loop() {
}
```

Comment: On an AVR-Arduino, each hardware timer controls two PWM pins. Results regarding timing/synchronization of the PWM signals may vary depending on the chosen pins.

Comment: @DataFiddler There are no requirements in the question concerning synchronous signals. ;-) I assume this is just an introductory experiment of a homework or laboratory assignment. But granted, with more and clear requirements, you _could_ have a point.

Comment: @busybee I understand `the time difference between the rising pulse of the traces` as a question about the synchronization  of the two PWM signals. But you're right, the task rather seems to aim at manual triggering of digital pins.